# Use bean without @MongoEntity annotation in Quarkus Panache MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have defined some beans to be stored in a Mongo Database. I am using Quarkus Panache MongoDB.

It works if I annotate the domain classes with @MongoEntity

```
@MongoEntity(collection="ThePerson")
public class Person  {
    public ObjectId id;
    public String name;
    ...
}
```

I want to avoid the @MongoEntity in these classes, to put these clases in a separated package and not depend on the Panache, or even any quarkus dependency.

How can I configure these external beans?

Why? I want to share a package to help other teams that don't use quarkus but will use the same model.

Comment: What you are asking for is not currently possible, but you can certainly request this feature on a Github issue.

Answer (score 0):

What if you share an `interface` with all the getters for example? So you can easily share your interfaces in packages/libs.

With this approach, suppose you are going to expose your models over some REST apis returning Jsons for your clients, you can create a utility jar/package that automatically converts the Json for your pojos.

```
//your abstration
interface BasePerson {
  ObjectId id();
  String name();
  ...
}
```

```
//your model/entity
@MongoEntity(collection="ThePerson")
public class Person implements BasePerson {
    public ObjectId id;
    public String name;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It could be a workaround, the other team should implement the concret class, duplicating code, we want to avoid it.

Comment: No no, you can expose a Pojo in your shared lib, and this Pojo implements the interface. You can even expose a deserializer (using Jackson or any other) to read your json and convert to your Pojo.
Expose directly your domain in general is not a good idea.